# Error: validation failed: Path is required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save the consession in mongoDb . It has some required fields . When I try to save it it shows validation error . But when I comment the required fields then its work . Why it is happening ?

**error**

Error: Consession validation failed: passType: Path `passType` is required.
properties: [Object],
kind: 'required',
path: 'passType',
value: undefined,
reason: undefined,
[Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
}
},
_message: 'Consession validation failed'
}

**order schema**

```
const consessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {

    fromStation: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },

    passType: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["I", "II"],
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    ticketPeriod: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["Monthly", "Quarterly"],
      default: "Monthly",
      required: true,
    },

      updated: Date,
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Consession = mongoose.model("Consession", consessionSchema);
```

**order controller**

```
exports.createOrder = (req, res) => {
  const consession = new Consession({
    fromStation: req.body.fromStation,
    passType: req.body.toStation,
    ticketPeriod: req.body.ticketPeriod,
  });


  consession.save((err, order) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(req.body);
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Failed to make order",
      });
    }
    return res.json({
      order,
    });
  });
};
```

**API handler**

```
export const createOrder = (userId, studentId, token, order) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/order/create/${userId}/${studentId}`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(order),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

**form input**

```js
const NewConsession = ({ match }) => {
  const [students, setStudents] = useState({
    fromStation: "",
    toStation: "",
    passType: "",
    ticketPeriod: "",
    error: "",
  });
  const { user, token } = isAuthenticated();
  const {
    fromStation,
    toStation,
    passType,
    ticketPeriod,
    error,
  } = students;


  useEffect(() => {
    preload(match.params.studentId);
  }, []);

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setStudents({ ...students, error: "" });
    createOrder(user._id, match.params.studentId, token, {
      fromStation,
      toStation,
      passType,
      ticketPeriod,
    })
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.error) {
          console.log(data.error);
          setStudents({ ...students, error: error });
        } else {
          console.log(data);
          setStudents({
            ...students,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(console.log("error in order"));
  };

  const handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
    setStudents({ ...students, [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const form = () => {
    return (
      <div
        className="container card bg-info text-white  "
        style={{ width: "600px", height: "400px" }}
      >

            <div className="bg-dark rounded">request Details</div>
            <div className="row form-group col-md-12 mt-2">
              <input
                type="text"
                onChange={handleChange("fromStation")}
                name="fromStation"
                className="form-control offset-md-2  col-md-4 "
                placeholder="From Station"
                value={fromStation}
              />
              <input
                name="toStation"
                className="form-control  col-md-4 ml-4"
                placeholder="to Station"
                value="xyz"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="row form-group col-md-12">
              <select
                onChange={handleChange("passType")}
                className="form-control offset-md-2  col-md-4 "
                placeholder="Pass Type"
                name="passType"
              >
                <option value="I">I</option>
                <option value="II">II</option>
              </select>
              <select
                onChange={handleChange("ticketPeriod")}
                className="form-control  col-md-4 ml-4"
                placeholder="Ticket Period"
                name="ticketPeriod"
              >
                <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
                <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <Link
              type="submit"
              onClick={onSubmit}
              className="btn  btn-block btn-outline-warning  rounded text-danger"
              style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
            >
              Request For Consession
            </Link>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: try logging the value of that field right before you save.